# I can't select items in the listview

Tags: android-studio, listview

I have a list view with custom adapter in my android application. but I can't select the elements in the list view. I have tried to select the item using the list view on item click listener but it doesn't work .please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    name_item = (String) ((TextView) view).getText();
                    // do something after click item
                }
            });
```